# List all files inside an Firebase Storage folder on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the list of all files present in a Firebase Storage folder (with files of subfolders...etc...) but but I am having some problems. As Firebase Storage does not support this functionality I have to code it myself, I wrote the code below, it works but when I call it unfortunately the result is not the right one, I have the first pass of the list out I need the last when all the results are in the list.
How do I proceed ?

```
storageReference.listAll().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ListResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ListResult> task) {
                            System.out.println(buildFireBaseFiles(task.getResult(), null));
                            //downloadFiles(buildFireBaseFiles(task.getResult()), data_view);
                        }
                    });
```

-

```
List<Uri> uris_ = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Uri> buildFireBaseFiles(final ListResult listResult, final @Nullable List<Uri> uris) {
    if (uris == null)
        uris_ = new ArrayList<>();
    else
        uris_ = uris;
    if (listResult != null) {
        if (listResult.getPrefixes().size() != 0 && listResult.getPrefixes().size() != -1) {
            for (StorageReference s : listResult.getItems()) {
                uris_.add(Uri.parse(s.getPath()));
            }
            for (StorageReference s : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                s.listAll().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ListResult> task) {
                        buildFireBaseFiles(task.getResult(), uris_);
                        System.out.println("1 " + uris_.size());
                    }
                });
            }
        } else if (listResult.getItems().size() != 0 && listResult.getItems().size() != -1) {
            for (StorageReference s : listResult.getItems()) {
                uris_.add(Uri.parse(s.getPath()));
            }
        }
    }
    if (uris != null)
                System.out.println("2 " + uris.size());

    return uris_;
}
```

Output:

```
I/System.out: 2 3
I/System.out: 1 3
I/System.out: 2 5
I/System.out: 1 5
...
after a while
...
I/System.out: 2 83
I/System.out: 1 83
```

but the return list size (buildFireBaseFiles(task.getResult(), null).size()) is 3 not 83

Edit : I think the problem is

```
s.listAll().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ListResult> task) {
                        buildFireBaseFiles(task.getResult(), uris_);
                        System.out.println("1 " + uris_.size());
                    }
                });
```

because buildFireBaseFiles is a recursive call and recursive call don't work inside onComplete

Re-Edit : **SOLUTION FOUND (!!It's not the best way but it works!!)**

```
    private List<Uri> uris_ = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Uri> buildFireBaseFiles(final ListResult listResult, final @Nullable List<Uri> uris) {
    if(uris ==null)
        uris_ =new ArrayList<>();
    if(listResult !=null){
        if (listResult.getPrefixes().size() != 0 && listResult.getPrefixes().size() != -1) {
            for (StorageReference s : listResult.getItems()) {
                uris_.add(Uri.parse(s.getPath()));
            }
            for (StorageReference s : listResult.getPrefixes()) {
                final Task<ListResult> b = s.listAll();
                //Bad, can block the UI, better to run in a Thread !
                while (!b.isComplete());
                buildFireBaseFiles(b.getResult(), uris_);
                /*
                Good Usage but don't allow Recursive Call...
                b.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ListResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ListResult> task) {
                        uris_ = buildFireBaseFiles(task.getResult(), uris_);
                        System.out.println("1 " + uris_.size());
                    }
                });
                */
            }
        } else if (listResult.getItems().size() != 0 && listResult.getItems().size() != -1) {
            for (StorageReference s : listResult.getItems()) {
                uris_.add(Uri.parse(s.getPath()));
            }
        }
    }
    return uris_;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have not include the code that prints `2`. Note sure if that was intentional, but since you show its output it would be good to include the code that prints that output too (or remove the output, if it isn't relevant).

Comment: Yep, I corrected.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: When i call buildFireBaseFiles i want the full list (actually i only have the first pass
I/System.out: 2 3
I/System.out: 1 3
I want the list when it's complete
I/System.out: 2 83
I/System.out: 1 83
buildFireBaseFiles(task.getResult(), null).size() need to return 83 not 3

Answer (score 0):

```
root.child('images').listAll()
```

use this `listAll()` with your storage reference to get the list of all files in that folder.